# Artefact at joints within BSplineCurve of low Opacity

Tags: graphics, splines

I want to eliminate the dots of higher opacity that occur at the joints within a `BSplineCurve` of low opacity. Small rectangles of greater opacity, shown below, become small circles when `CapForm["Round"]` is set, confirming the cause as overlap of spline segments. `BezierCurve` does not show these changes in opacity; however, the frequent sharp corners of a `BezierCurve` do not work for my application.

```
Block[{p}, SeedRandom[1729];
   p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}];
   Graphics[{Thickness[0.05], Opacity[0.4], BSplineCurve[p]}]]
```

[image: spline opacity artefact]

I also tried a `BSplineFunction` of the points, `f = BSplineFunction[p]`, then a `Line` between samples of the function, `Line[Table[f[x],{x,0,1,0.005]]`. The overlapped joints persist. Is there a way to cure these "measles"?

EDIT

Code posted. Using the example in belisarius's comment gives the same curve as in his linked *.png, however the opacity dots persist. I am using version 10.3.0, 64 bit on Linux.

SOLUTION

Wolfram support fixed the problem with the following setting,

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PolylineGroupSize -> 250];
```

saying "This should produce the proper results at the expense of a little bit of speed. You can change the numeric value to meet your needs."

Comment: Please give us some sample code so we can help you.

Comment: `Graphics[{Opacity[.3], Thickness[.08], 
  BSplineCurve[
   pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {4, -2}, {5, 1}, {1, 
      1}, {3, 3}}]}]` results in  http://i.stack.imgur.com/lrcPW.png (Mma v9) Please post your code

Comment: Looks fine with v10.0.1, Win7, 64 bit.

Comment: Looks like a "new version" bug then. Could someone confirm with 10.3 and add the "bugs" tag?

Comment: No problem with 10.3 on Windows 10

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing [the unsightly joints Kenny sees](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zIDfm.png) (using belisarius's example). I am also on 10.3 on Linux (Xubuntu).

Comment: `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PolylineGroupSize -> n]` improves the image up to `n` around `1000`, but it never gets better than this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/glxmh.png (Mac M1 Max, V13.0.1).